# switch between limited textfields

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitextfield, limit

I would like to write 4 numbers in a textfield (`codeA`) an if there are 4 numbers inside I want to select another field (`codeB`). I want codeB to be also limited to 4 numbers. but if I make it a delegate of View Controller, the application crashes.
my code in .h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *codeA;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *codeB;
```

my code in .m:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
if ([codeA.text length] > 3) {
    codeA.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:4];
    [codeB becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
if ([codeB.text length] > 3) {
    codeB.text = [codeB.text substringToIndex:4];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

if `codeB` is not delegate of View Controller it works, but B isn't limited.

Comment: Crashes?  Are you getting any error messages?  If so, please post.

Comment: if I Build it, it shows me no issues, but when i run it the app closes when i try to get data in codeB